# Mouse over not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, colors, highlight

I am trying to make a button highlight when the cursor goes over it 
**the html is:**

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js></script>
<scrips src="index.html"></script>
</head>
```

**and the js in index.js**

```
$(".button").mouseenter(function(){
 $(".button).css("background-color", "cyan");
 $(".button).css("color", "white");
});
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in the Javascript. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").mouseenter(function(){
$(".button").css("background-color", "cyan");
$(".button").css("color", "white");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nroqjuhn/

Comment: What did you do other than fix the quote typo?

Answer (score 0):

Missed quotes in jQuery and html

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <button class="button" type="button">Change my color</button>
   <script src="custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js

```
$(".button").mouseenter(function(){
 $(".button").css("background-color", "cyan");
 $(".button").css("color", "white");
});
```

Comment: Typos should be handled with a comment, it's not worth a full-blown answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").mouseenter(()=>{$(".button")
   .css({"background-color":"cyan","color":"black"});
});

$(".button").mouseleave(()=>{$(".button")
   .css({"background-color":"#0084ff","color":"white"});
});
```